# PHP md5 function which gets hex input?

Tags: php, md5

I've been trying to get an MD5 function in PHP, which gets hex input. Is there some way to use the standard `md5()` with hex input or is there some library which can supply this md5 function?

for example:

```
$str="a789234b2f";
echo md5($str);
```

gives out the hash of the string "a789234b2f" instead if the hex 0xa789234b2f.

Comment: you can run md5 on a hex string just fine

Comment: Do you get any errors? What have you tried?

Comment: Just to be clear are you just wanting to make a hash of a hex code e.g. `#ffffff` = `54922f2e920ba8346f6dc0fba343d673`?

Comment: I don't get any errors, it's just that when I enter a hex expression(e.g "aa313b92") it computes the md5 while referring to it as the string "aa313b92" instead of a hexodecimal expression.

Comment: To Ross Wilson, the answer is yes.

Comment: you are going to need to add some code examples to the question for us to be able to understand your issue

Comment: md5 takes the input you give it, any conversions you have to do yourself first.

Comment: It was an example, I didn't actually expected it to work, it was just to illustrate the situation, because it seemed like some people didn't understand what I was trying to say.

Comment: You could do with providing some examples of what you are trying to achieve. What you have given doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Since you said it's a Hex string `0xa789234b2f` then it implies it's a number.

Convert it to decimal using **[hexdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php)**

```
$str = "a789234b2f";
$str = hexdec($str); // 719560330031

echo md5($str); // 65B7AD465DB64D7871419186CBE0C22D
```